# key_load_public: invalid format after ssh-keygen

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

After updating Ubuntu to 16.04 I've some problem with ssh connection, now the connection require a password though my public key was copied in remote authorized_keys by ssh-copy-id. After a new ssh-copy-id i receive `key_load_public: invalid format`, to be sure of correct key format I've generated new key by `ssh-keygen` and re-launch ssh-copy-id but the result is the same `key_load_public: invalid format`, same as all ssh connection in which I have to type my password.

How can I generate a key and copy on my remote server without receiving this "invalid format" error?

```
ssh -v <user>@<host-name>:

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 57: Deprecated option "useroaming"
debug1: Connecting to <host-name> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<user>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <my_host>:22 as '<user>'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:2XmTTbzpU31c8OfZCyzMPspS9HE0VASPA7RliKRX5aA
The authenticity of host '<host-name> (<ip>)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2XmTTbzpU31c8OfZCyzMPspS9HE0VASPA7RliKRX5aA.
```

Comment: What key type are you using? What does the complete debug log look like?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with sofware development. For questions about general ssh usage, you should consider asking on [su] or [unix.se] instead. Having said that, I don't see an invalid format error in the ssh debug output that you included in your question. If you think this question is on topic here, you should [edit] your question to include an ssh invocation that actually demonstrates the problem that you're having.

Comment: Ok, you are right! How I can move my question to Super User or Unix & Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh-keygen command to generate the key in remote machine then

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

Generate sshkey in the remote machine and Copy the .pub file to authorized keys , just execute the following command for that

```
cat <key>.pub >> authorized_keys
```

copy the other key file(private key) to your machine , then using that you can login. Use the following command for that

```
ssh -i <key-file> <username>@<ip>
```

If you want to implement ssh connection without the help of key file every time add the generated .pub file in your machine to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of remote machine so that you can login just by giving the ip or hostname

Comment: Thanks for the answer, one question this procedure can affect the ssh connections of other users? I'm not the only one which use ssh connection on this remote server

Comment: No , it wont unless you remove anything from authorized_keys file.

Comment: Super, now I try the procedure, I hope this can help me, thankyou very much!

Comment: All works fine until i try to use ssh with only the `user@hostname`, in this case I receive the same error: `key_load_public: invalid format`, in my authorized_key file I copied the content of .pub file generated on server, the strange thing is when i launch `ssh -i <key_file_path> user@host` the connection not require password. Any ideas?

Comment: For accessing from your machine ,the procedure is inverse ie; generate the key in your machine and copy the .pub file to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of remote machine. Also this is a passwordless authentication method which requires just the key as auth.

Comment: The procedure you described is the procedure I used before post my question (and i tried to describe with my bad english in my question), now, for completeness I try to re-make all the process in on my host and post the result

Comment: Also with the right procedure i receive the same error... I've no more ideas to how I can use ssh without password on this server

Comment: For some reason, secure for my own error, the public key was the same as the private key, all problems are solved by this command `ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub` which put in the id_rsa.pub the public key generated from private key, after this I have launched `ssh-copy-id <user>@<host>` for save the key in remote server authorized_keys. Now all work! Thanks to all for the support!